# Whose Google Drive is the recording saved while in a Google Meet?

Tags: google-drive, google-meet

In this pandemic period, the classes are being held online. Our college uses Google Suite which provides the feature of Google Meet. Some of our lectures need to be recorded. Sometimes our professor himself starts the recording and sometimes a student starts it. After it is completed, the recording gets saved randomly into one of the participant's Google Drive. The other participants can see whose Drive folder the recording is saved into by clicking the ***stop recording*** button in the options tab. Not all people see it, but I do it regularly to know whose folder it is saved to, so that we can ask that student to share. Some people do, but some of them deny by saying that "I am wrong, and that the video of the recording is not saved in their Drive folder!"

So my main question is, **how can I determine whose drive it is saved to?** I mean, is the stop recording showing incorrect name and location?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the matter is like this, since last three days I have been paying extra attention and even asked a couple of teachers to help me out with a demo experiment. And finally I am convinced that the recordings do get saved in the drive of the person whose name is being displayed on the pop-up screen when a participant clicks on the ***stop recording*** button.

Also, after the recording is completed, an email is received by the host of the meeting (in my case, the teacher), that the recording got saved into a certain person named *ABC's* drive.

So it is actually quite verified in my case, since I have my teachers to support me. From now on, you can also opt the technique of clicking on the ***stop recording*** button to know whose drive it is saved to, if you require the recordings for certain purpose, otherwise can approach the host of your meeting regarding the same. And mind you, you can save screenshots if you think someone may be in denial of providing the recordings (provided, you are taking it for good means).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From: https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10619995?hl=en-GB

> The recording link is also added to the Calendar event and saved to the meeting organiser’s Meet recordings folder in My Drive.

I find using the link in the Calendar event the easiest thing to use. Also remember the recording must be processed first, so may not be available immediately.